# Find period of $g$ if $f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{8}{1+x} + \frac{8}{{1-x}}}$ and $g(x) = \frac{4}{f(\sin x)}+\frac{4}{f(\cos x)}$

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

**The given question**

> $$f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{8}{1+x} + \frac{8}{{1-x}}}$$
> $$g(x) = \frac{4}{f(\sin x)}+\frac{4}{f(\cos x)}$$
> find period of $g(x)$?

**What I have done**

putting $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ in $f(x)$,

we get $\large{\frac{4}{\cos(x)}}$  and  $\large{\frac{4}{\sin(x)}}$ respectively.

Putting these in $g(x)$ we get $\sin(x) + \cos(x)$ which should have period $2\pi$ but the solution provided says that period of $g(x)$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
Why?

Comment: $f(\sin x) \neq \dfrac{4}{\sin x}$ and $f(\cos x) \neq \dfrac{4}{\cos x}$

Comment: f(cosx) = 4/sinx f(sinx) = 4/cosx doesn't make a diff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
f(\sin x) &= \sqrt{\dfrac{8}{1+\sin x} + \dfrac{8}{1-\sin x}} \qquad \qquad \\
&= 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{1-\sin^2 x}} \\
&= \dfrac{4}{\lvert \cos x \rvert} 
\end{align}
Similarly 
$$f(\cos x) = \dfrac{4}{\lvert \sin x\rvert}.$$
Thus 
$$g(x) = \lvert \cos x \rvert + \lvert \sin x \rvert,$$
and the period of $g(x)$ is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

In effect $\lvert \cos x \rvert$ and $\lvert \sin x \rvert$ are both $\pi-$periodic but one also has :
$$\lvert \cos(x+\pi/2)\rvert = \lvert \sin x\rvert,$$
which implies $$g(x) = g(x+\pi/2).$$

Comment: why root of cos^2(x) and sin^2(x) is taken |cosx| and |sinx|? i mean sin and cos can be negative

Comment: and the answer key says the answer is pi/2

Comment: @defcon2 $\sqrt{x^2} = \lvert x \rvert$.

Comment: thanks for answering btw why |x|? x can be + and - both. we right (4)^1/2 = +- 2

Comment: I got it, f(x) wouldn't be a function if it gives 2 values ie. + and - cos(x) that's why we take |cos(x)| :)

Comment: @defcon2 See the [Square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Properties_and_uses) page on Wikipedia.